# Function pointers compilation error on AIX

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, function-pointers, aix

I'm trying to compile some C code in IBM AIX, but it seems that it has some serious problems with functions pointers.

Here is some code that doesn't compile:

```
typedef int (*strategy_fn)(const unsigned short va_niveau_trace, const unsigned int va_indentation_trace, const char* va_finalstring);

typedef struct strategy_tab_item_
{
  TraceStrategy strategy;
  strategy_fn fn;
}strategy_tab_item, *strategy_tab_item_ptr;

const strategy_tab_item tab_strategy[] =
{
    {TRACE_NO_BUFFERING, trace_process_no_buffering},
    {TRACE_LOOSE_CURRENT, trace_process_loose_current},
    {TRACE_LOOSE_OLDEST, trace_process_loose_oldest},
    {TRACE_AUTO_SYNC, trace_process_auto_sync}
};
```

The typedef as it is written in the code above (2 definitions at the same time) is not supported by AIX, I separated them like this:

```
typedef struct strategy_tab_item_
{
  TraceStrategy strategy;
  strategy_fn fn;
} strategy_tab_item;

typedef struct strategy_tab_item_ *strategy_tab_item_ptr;
```

now the `strategy_fn` is not recognized (syntax error).

Comment: 1) Don't `typedef` pointers. It just obfuscates your code by hiding the semantics. 2) See [ask] and provide a [mcve]. It is not clear what the actual problem is. The code shown in the unformated text seems not to be reevant for this problem 3) A type missmatch will not result in a syntax error message.

Comment: Give us the error, please

Comment: As an exception to @Olaf's good general rule, I'm inclined to accept typedefs of *function* pointers, such as your first typedef.  These serve a useful purpose, and C has no viable alternative other than giving a full function declarator wherever you want to declare a pointer to a function.

Comment: Sorry guys for bothering you, there was somme c++ code, after this code causing the illogical error. (an inline keyword) when i removed it everything is working fine. Is it possible to delete this question, cuz it's useless now ?

Answer (score 1):

The code you quoted is incomplete. Try this:

```
typedef int strategy_fn (const unsigned short va_niveau_trace, 
        const unsigned int va_indentation_trace,
        const char *va_finalstring);

strategy_fn trace_process_no_buffering,
            trace_process_loose_current,
            trace_process_loose_oldest,
            trace_process_auto_sync;

typedef enum TraceStrategy {
    TRACE_NO_BUFFERING,
    TRACE_LOOSE_CURRENT,
    TRACE_LOOSE_OLDEST,
    TRACE_AUTO_SYNC
} TraceStrategy;

typedef struct strategy_tab_item_
{
  TraceStrategy strategy;
  strategy_fn *fn;
} strategy_tab_item, *strategy_tab_item_ptr;

const strategy_tab_item tab_strategy[] =
{
    {TRACE_NO_BUFFERING, trace_process_no_buffering},
    {TRACE_LOOSE_CURRENT, trace_process_loose_current},
    {TRACE_LOOSE_OLDEST, trace_process_loose_oldest},
    {TRACE_AUTO_SYNC, trace_process_auto_sync}
};
```

Comment: Sure, I compiled it on AIX.